# How do I estimate where a faulty partition begins or ends in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04

I've reinstalled Ubuntu, and somehow I messed up the old partition. I can see it in the disk utility. It's the 253GB one that's highlighted below. When I try to use one of the disk recovery tools (ddrescue or test_disk) they ask me for an approximate location of the lost partition. The problem is that I don't know how to get that approximate partition.

As you can see, this is considered a peripheral device, and that's only because the 2 500GB hdd are running in RAID 0. (This also means that gparted cannot recognize these partitions, it only sees the two 500GB disks.)

Anyone know how I can estimate where that partition starts and ends?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)? BTW, if your data is gone, you probably shouldn't write to the partition table, just copy the results off.